# Get all geopoints between 2 endpoints in Google Map V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need help related to Google Map V3.
Is it possible to get all the geopoints between 2 endpoints in V3.

In V2 i have some code as mentioned below

```
var poly = directions.getPolyline()
// loop through all the points
var p = poly.getVertex(x);
// get lat lang
p.lat(); p.lng();
```

but there is no equivalent code in V3 to get all the lat, lang between the 2 locations.
can you please help me to get all the lat, lang between the 2 endpoints.

I am not sure whether i have provided all the information here, please let me know f you have any inputs.

Thanks,
-Sharath

Answer (score 0):

you may either parse the `overview_path`-property of a route(which contains the LatLng's of the route in a simplified version) or iterate over `route->legs->steps->path` to retrieve the complete list of LatLng's

Comment: Thanks Molle foy input, yes your solution is working for.     -Sharath